# How dynamically change the connection for all Model to the database in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I want to dynamically change the connection to the database, get the current database name from the function

`$DataSource = $this->getDataSource()->config['database'];`

and save it to the model  "CurrentDb", and that's the problem, I can not read read this model in __construct() AppModel  and set for all models of a single connection to the database using

```
$this->setDataSource($current_bd);
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Maybe you are trying to do something you don't have to do.

Comment: There are 2 databases, test and production, wanted to quickly switch between them without editing database.php

Comment: I suggest not to change your live version to another database once live, ever. It is better to have running two sites next to each other. `example.com` and `dev.example.com` where `dev.*` is linked to another database. This will also give you the opportunity to develop new features and fix bugs and test it through without having to take your main website offline. TL;DR, never take your live website down to test new features. Make sure it is thoroughly tested locally and/or on your develop server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jelmer, but I had to use that dynamic change, I made it, made through the component Sessions

Comment: Can you explain why? I'm really curious why you "had" to do it.

Comment: ok Jelmer, on one site I have made two different functionality, and that they could be tested separately, each connected to its database, but the database structure and data for Similar Containers